# Are there any visual tools for Python unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, user-interface, nose, nosetests

I'm writing quite a few unit tests and using [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to run them.  Nose certainly makes it nice and easy to run tests, but the output can be pretty cluttered at the best of times, and a downright mess at others, depending on warnings and errors.

I was wondering if there are any visual tools that wrap nose so that the feedback cleaner.  A results grid showing test names, run times and indicating success/failure status with colours would be a huge visual aide.  Better still, if it could split up the error messages and tracebacks on a case by case basis, it would *really* cut down on the amount of clutter when a large number of tests fail on a major change.

This is starting to read like a wishlist, but does anything even *close* to this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638127/is-there-a-gui-for-nosetests).

It doesn't look like there's a standardized GUI for nosetests (as in, standardized for just the python interface). There seems to be a few GUI plugins for nosetests depending on which IDE you're using - a quick search brought up [this link](http://mysite.verizon.net/bcorfman/knose.html) for Komodo.

However, there are many other GUI based unit testing frameworks out there for Python - have you tried [PyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @nosklo: Whoops. Cheers for that.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the PyUnit GUI leaves a lot to be desired in terms of feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what you can do is to use the [jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) integration server, we use it with py.test and phpunit (it is really simple to use it with any other testing framework), it provides us some fancy (and useful!) graphs containing

- Number of tests that run
- Number of tests passing/failing
- The stack trace for the failed tests
- Execution times for tests
- Code coverage for the tests
- You can also relate it to git/svn/mercurial...

[Here](http://www.rhonabwy.com/wp/2009/11/04/setting-up-a-python-ci-server-with-hudson/) you have an example of how to configure hudson (for the record, jenkins is a fork of hudson, so the instructions are still valid :), in order to provide the elements from your wishlist.

An easier option is to use a IDE as PyCharm, it has integration with nosetests, and will tell you which tests passed/failed and its times, however, jenkis stores historical data.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Nose plugins page](http://nose-plugins.jottit.com/)? A quick glance revealed at least a couple that stated they could provide a GUI interface.

Comment: Only one said it could and it needed to be integrated into the Komodo IDE.